# How to ignore errors in mysqldbcopy

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Is there an option to ignore errors and continue copy in mysqldbcopy

Comment: No such command-line option. Copy databases one-by-one using separate mysqldbcopy commands.

Comment: @Akina It's not about separate databases. If one table fails, it should continue with rest of the tables

Comment: In General, the continuation of the copying operation after an error occures will result in the copy will be incorrect (data/integrity damaged). So the continuation of the process after an error makes no sense. The application finished its work for to save a time, and no alternative provided.